# How do I convert an email dataset into a hierarchy for a sunburst diagram?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, sunburst-diagram

the dataset is a json file like this
[{from: x, to: y}, {from: x, to: z}] and so on.

```
    partitioned_data = d3.partition().size([2*Math.PI, 100]);
    root_node = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(d => d.size);
    partitioned_data(root_node);
```

this is what I have so far

I'm getting this as the root node:
[image: root node]

... and `root_node.children` is still undefined. I'm using an example dataset which is just `99->77, 77->112 and 112->82`. I want it to give a hierarchy of `root_node = 99` and `root_node.children[0] = 77` and so on.

Comment: Please provide more info; what's the current result? How does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: @ChrisG I have added more details

Comment: The data you pass to `d3.hierarchy` is in a wrong format... Can you provide a sample of your data instean of a screenshot?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky i have added the example data I'm using

Comment: OK, I get it. The parent id is `fromId` and the child's is `toId`. Right?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky yes

Comment: Please do ***not*** deface your question. This is not fair to the volunteers that put in the effort to answer it on their own free time, nor to the future users of this site.

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason why you cannot convert your email data into an hierarchical one:

Your data represents a **linked non-hierarchical graph**, where every node can be linked to everyone else.

The d3.hierarchy requires data, where each node can have only one parent and no loops allowed. If you identify the parent by `fromId`, the child by `toId`, and your data looks like this:

```
[
  {fromId: 1, toId: 2},
  {fromId: 2, toId: 3},
  {fromId: 3, toId: 1},
]
```

... you have a link loop and **cannot create an hierarchy** from that data.

Comment: Then is there a way I can represent the data to draw it as a sunburst diagram?

Comment: I'm not sure sunburst is kind of visualization that conforms your data. I suppose you should use a linked graph instead. Here is an example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642

Comment: Or maybe a chord diagram: https://observablehq.com/@d3/directed-chord-diagram

Comment: Is there a way then to represent it as a sunburst with the base being all the fromIds and the connection being all the toIds?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Directed chord is an excellent example!